# Why can't I train overfeat network with convolution layer 1x1

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

I'm trying to modify tensorflow slim overfeat network to classify small image classes, image size is 60*60 and 3 classes. 
I'm use tensorflow v0.12 on Ubuntu 14.04 with TITAN X GPU.

My first network is

```
    import tensorflow as tf

    slim = tf.contrib.slim
    trunc_normal = lambda stddev: tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0.0, stddev)


    def overfeat_arg_scope(weight_decay=0.0005):
      with slim.arg_scope(
          [slim.conv2d, slim.fully_connected],
          activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
          weights_regularizer=slim.l2_regularizer(weight_decay),
          biases_initializer=tf.constant_initializer()):
        with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d], padding='SAME'):
          with slim.arg_scope([slim.max_pool2d], padding='VALID') as arg_sc:
            return arg_sc


    def overfeat(inputs,
                 num_classes=1000,
                 is_training=True,
                 dropout_keep_prob=0.5,
                 spatial_squeeze=False,
                 reuse=None,
                 scope='overfeat'):
      with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'overfeat', [inputs], reuse=reuse) as sc:
        end_points_collection = sc.name + '_end_points'
        # Collect outputs for conv2d, fully_connected and max_pool2d
        with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.fully_connected, slim.max_pool2d],
                            outputs_collections=end_points_collection):
          net = slim.conv2d(inputs, 64, 3, padding='VALID',
                            scope='conv11')
          net = slim.conv2d(inputs, 128, 3, padding='VALID',
                            scope='conv12')
          net = slim.max_pool2d(net, 2, scope='pool1')
          net = slim.conv2d(net, 128, 3, padding='VALID', scope='conv2')
          net = slim.max_pool2d(net, 2, scope='pool2')
          net = slim.conv2d(net, 256, 3, scope='conv3')
          net = slim.conv2d(net, 256, 3, scope='conv4')
          net = slim.conv2d(net, 256, 3, scope='conv5')
          net = slim.max_pool2d(net, 2, scope='pool5')
          with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d],
                              weights_initializer=trunc_normal(0.005),
                              biases_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1)):
            # Use conv2d instead of fully_connected layers.
            net = slim.conv2d(net, 512, 3, padding='VALID', scope='fc6')
            net = slim.dropout(net, dropout_keep_prob, is_training=is_training,
                               scope='dropout6')
            net = slim.conv2d(net, 1024, 1, scope='fc7')
            with tf.variable_scope('Logits'):
                #pylint: disable=no-member
                if is_training:
                    net = slim.avg_pool2d(net, net.get_shape()[1:3], padding='VALID',
                                      scope='AvgPool_1a_8x8')
                net = slim.conv2d(
                    net,
                    num_classes, 1,
                    activation_fn=None,
                    normalizer_fn=None,
                    biases_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(),
                    scope='fc9')

                net = slim.dropout(net, dropout_keep_prob, is_training=is_training,
                                   scope='Dropout')
          # Convert end_points_collection into a end_point dict.
          end_points = slim.utils.convert_collection_to_dict(end_points_collection)
          if spatial_squeeze:
            net = tf.squeeze(net, [1, 2], name='fc8/squeezed')
            end_points[sc.name + '/fc8'] = net
          return net, end_points

    def inference(images, num_classes, keep_probability, phase_train=True, weight_decay=0.0, reuse=None):
        batch_norm_params = {
            # Decay for the moving averages.
            'decay': 0.995,
            # epsilon to prevent 0s in variance.
            'epsilon': 0.001,
            # force in-place updates of mean and variance estimates
            'updates_collections': None,
        }
        with slim.arg_scope(overfeat_arg_scope()):
            return overfeat(images, num_classes, is_training=phase_train,
                  dropout_keep_prob=keep_probability, reuse=reuse)
```

I'm use cross entroy loss with tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits function.

And train result is
[Loss And Accuracy with one 1x Conv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHpCU.jpg)

This result is passable.
I'm trying to add one 1x1 conv after fc7 because I think 1x1 conv is same full connected layer and may be improve accuracy.

```
        ...
        net = slim.conv2d(net, 1024, 1, scope='fc7')
        net = slim.conv2d(net, 1024, 1, scope='fc7_1')
        ...
```

But I got unreliable result :
[Loss And Accuracy with two 1x1 Conv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cObm.jpg)

This network don't be optimized with loss 1.

Why I can't add more 1x1 conv or fc layers?

And how can I improve this network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1,1) convolution layer is not a fully connected layer. if you want to implement fully connected layer as convolution layer you should add last layer kernel size of the layer before.

(if the feature map of the layer before is 50x50 your last layer should have a kernel of 50 x 50). convolution layer with (1,1) kernel size is similar ro mlp layer. if tyou want to undertsand more how it works read this paper [Network in Network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4400)

If I understood well, you want to get ride of the fully connected layer. so you have to do two things:

- assure that you are reducing the last layer to the size of your class by using convolution layer (1,1) with channel equal to your output classes.
- use global average pooling to reduce the feature map to 1 and then feed the result to the softmax.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I found it very useful!

Comment: Actually the featuer map of the before is 1x1 when input image size is 60.
So I think 1x1 conv is same fc in channel, and add 1x1Conv with 1024 channel.
But I got result is very poor and there is no anything optimization.
How can I improve this net?

Comment: you can see 1x1 conv as cross channel reduction and not as fully connected. what is similar to fully connected is conv layer with kernel size of the feature maps size. if your network is not converging try to change parameters, play a bit with optimization methods, inlcude more data and at then end change structure.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I'll try with optimization methods.

Answer (score 0):

1x1 Convolution is not the same as a fully connected layer. Alone the parameter count is vastly different. A 1x1 Convolution is the weighted sum of all the pixel, which are in the same location in the image, from all the previous filter outputs.

A fully connected layer on the other hand takes all the pixels of all the filters into account for every new pixel in the current layer.

You should take a look at http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/contents.html to understand convolutions better.

For the final layers fully connected layers are used to combine the features extracted in the previous layers and combine them to the final output.

Comment: actually I see [link]http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12830/how-are-1x1-convolutions-the-same-as-a-fully-connected-layer.
I understood if layer size(width, height) is 1x1 then 1x1 conv is sampe fc in depth.
So I add 1x1 conv before  last 1x1conv.

Comment: <pre><code>
            if is_training:
                net = slim.avg_pool2d(net, net.get_shape()[1:3], padding='VALID',
                                  scope='AvgPool_1a_8x8')
            net = slim.conv2d(net, 1024, 1, scope='fc7_1')
            net = slim.conv2d(
                net,
                num_classes, 1,
                activation_fn=None,
                normalizer_fn=None,
                biases_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(),
                scope='fc9')
</code></pre>

But I got the same poor result. Why I can't improve overfeat net with fc?